# Tengo problemas insertando registros en codeignaiter con ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

de antemano gracias por sus posibles comentarios.
Estoy tratando de implementar código ajax en codeigniter y no logro que funcione. No se si falte configurar algo en el framework porque tampoco me funciona cuando hago las consultas a la base de datos ya que no puedo escribir el resultado en un label.

A continuación adjunto el código:

en la vista home:

```
    <form  id="formComentar" name="formComentar">
       <input type="text" id="idU" name="idU"  value=" <?php echo $usuario['idUsuario']?>">
       <input type="text" id="idPubli" name="idPubli" value=" <?php echo $row['idpublicacion']?>">
       <input type="text" id="comentario" name="comentario">
       <button id="btnComentar" name="btnComentar">Comentar</button>
    </form>
```

en el controlador Publicaciones

```
public function comentar(){
    $idPublicacion=$this->input->post('idPubli');
    $idUser=$this->input->post('idU');
    $contenidoComentario=$this->input->post('comentario');

    $data = array(
        'idPublicacion'=>$idPublicacion,
        'idUser'=>$idUser,
        'contenidoComentario'=>$contenidoComentario
    );
    $this->Publicaciones_Model->insertarComentario($data);
    }
```

En el modelo Publicaciones_Model

```
public function insertarComentario($data){

    return $this->db->insert('comentarios',$data);

}
```

En la base de datos, Tabla comentarios, campos: idPublicacion, idUser, contenidoComentario

script (por el momento está en el head de la vista home)

```
        <script language="javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#btnComentar").click(function(){
           var idPublicacion= $('#idPubli').val();
           var idUser= $('#idU').val();
           var comentario= $('#comentario').val();

           if(comentario!=""){
            $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url:"Publicaciones/comentar",
             data: {
              'idPublicacion': idPublicacion,
              'idUser': idUser,
              'contenidoComentario': comentario
             },
             error : function () {  
              alert ('Algo anda mal');
             },
             success: function(data) {
               alert('comentario insertado');
            }
          });
         }
        else{
          alert('Escriba su comentario');
        }
      });
     });
     </script>
```

al ejecutar no muestra ningún alert y no se inserta el registro en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿De qué modo indicas al servidor que cuando sea esta URL `url:"Publicaciones/comentar` se procesen los datos que mandas vía Ajax. No uso CI, por eso pregunto, no sé si en ese framework se hace el control de rutas de un modo particular

Comment: Aunque no se como responder directamente la pregunta de las rutas, no creo que ese sea el problema, porque cuando lo hago desde el action del form action="publicaciones/comentar", funciona perfectamente, lo que pasa es que no quiero que se recargue la pàgina y por eso busco hacerlo con ajax.

Comment: donde esta tu servidor???? local o remotamente??

Comment: En la pregunta original no me deja insertar comentarios, disculpen responder en un lugar no adecuado.

Comment: Estoy trabajando local en xampp

Comment: @leoncenteno Implementé tu sugerencia y "algo anda mal".  consola : reload.js:22 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
init @ reload.js:22
2home?idU=+5&idPubli=+82&comentario=Llámame+5142000&btnComentar=:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
api.ciuvo.com/api/analyze?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A800%2F&version=2.1.3&tag=threesixty&uuid=68C0CA2F-DEF8-4DF1-9332-39BE9167E9FF:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: podria ser muchas cosas que te da bad request, pero mira esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017081/getting-400-bad-request-error-in-jquery-ajax-post en ingles, se necesita parsear los datos del form como json.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu inserción funciona bien directamente recargando la pagina, quiere de decir que tu problema es la función con el ajax, puede ser como pasas la url, en lo particular me gusta usar "base_url()" de codeigniter, por ejemplo: , eso te creara una ruta absoluta estilo http:// dominio/Publicaciones/comentar

tu función debería quedar asi:

```js
<script language="javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#btnComentar").click(function(){
           var idPublicacion= $('#idPubli').val();
           var idUser= $('#idU').val();
           var comentario= $('#comentario').val();

           if(comentario!=""){
            $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url:"<?php echo base_url('Publicaciones/comentar'); ?>",
             data: {
              'idPublicacion': idPublicacion,
              'idUser': idUser,
              'contenidoComentario': comentario
             },
             error : function () {  
              alert ('Algo anda mal');
             },
             success: function(data) {
               alert('comentario insertado');
            }
          });
         }
        else{
          alert('Escriba su comentario');
        }
      });
     });
     </script>
```

Eso te debería funcionar sino revisa la consola del navegador para observar que mas te arroja.